# Number of loop tokens used in a function of python

Tags: python

```
def my_func():
    t = 10
    while(t > 0):
        t = t - 1
    for item in range(10):
       pass
```

Is there some easy way in Python to know that two loop constructs are getting used in the above code?

I am trying to build a coding platform where I want to restrict users to using just **one** loop to solve a question, so this information can be precious for checking and restricting the users.

Comment: Use the `ast` module to parse the code. Then you can scan the parse tree for multiple loop keywords (`for` and `while`).

Comment: well, was going to post an answer using `dis` but you can't catch while loops with `dis` since the op codes just use POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE and POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE which are identical to if statements so ast on the source code is your best bet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others mentioned, you could use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

```py
code = """
def my_func():
    t = 10
    while(t > 0):
        t = t - 1
    for item in range(10):
        pass
"""
```

```py
import ast
from typing import List, Union

class LoopVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self._loops: List[Union[ast.While, ast.For]] = []
    
    @property
    def count(self) -> int:
        return len(self._loops)

    @property
    def loops(self) -> List[Union[ast.While, ast.For]]:
        return self._loops

    def visit_While(self, node: ast.While) -> None:
        self._loops.append(node)
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_For(self, node: ast.For) -> None:
        self._loops.append(node)
        self.generic_visit(node)

tree = ast.parse(code)

visitor = LoopVisitor()
visitor.visit(tree)

print(visitor.count)
```

More information about `ast.NodeVisitor` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) and [here](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html#working-on-the-tree).

---

Alternatively you could also use [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html). However, it will only work with syntactically valid Python code.

```py
import io
import tokenize

def count_loops(code: str) -> int:

    count = 0

    for token in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(code.encode("utf-8")).readline):
        if token.type == tokenize.NAME and token.string in ("for", "while"):
            count += 1

    return count

print(count_loops(code))
```

More information about `tokenize` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) and [here](https://www.asmeurer.com/brown-water-python)

---

If you want to use a third-party library, you could also investigate [`parso`](https://github.com/davidhalter/parso) using `parso.python.tokenize.tokenize`:

```py
from parso.python import tokenize

def count_loops(code: str) -> int:

    count = 0

    for token in tokenize.tokenize(code, version_info=(3, 9, 0)):
        if token.type == tokenize.NAME and token.string in ("for", "while"):
            count += 1

    return count

print(count_loops(code))
```

Or, by using `parso.parse`, however, please note that I only tested the example against the code example in your question. It may not work universally.

```py
from parso import parse
from parso.tree import BaseNode
from parso.python.tree import ForStmt, WhileStmt

node: BaseNode = parse(code, version="3.9")

def count_loops(node: BaseNode) -> int:
    count = 0
    for child in node.children:
        if isinstance(child, (ForStmt, WhileStmt)):
            count += 1
        elif isinstance(child, BaseNode):
            count += count_loops(child)
    return count

print(count_loops(node))
```

---

Here is also a solution using [`asttokens`](https://asttokens.readthedocs.io/en/latest):

```py
import asttokens

def count_loops(code: str) -> int:

    count = 0

    for token in asttokens.ASTTokens(code).tokens:
        if token.string in ("for", "while"):
            count += 1

    return count

print(count_loops(code))
```